# Primefaces calendar return string

Tags: jsf, primefaces, calendar

I want to store the selected date from a primefaces calendar in a String property with the format yyyy/MM/dd. Can I do what?

I was thinking at something like:

```
 <p:calendar value="#{bean.birthDate}" pattern="yyyy/MM/dd" />
```

where birthDate is a String.

Comment: Why exactly would you use a wrong format for the data it holds? What problem exactly are you trying to solve by only storing the formatted date instead of the real date?

Comment: @BalusC I will use the inputed date along with some other inputs to build a jpql query. The query could look like: SELECT r FROM User r WHERE r.birthdate < 'birthDate' 
where birthDate will be the inputed String

Comment: Just convert to string over there if you really need to for some unclear reason? (JPA also just supports real dates)

Comment: You should only make the date a String when and if you need it for display output. JPA can work wiht java.util.Date just fine, and you save yourself some CPU and a lot of headache for someone else when your code is viewed by others. Unless its a school homework, and your teacher won't allow you to use Date for some obscure reason.